# Migrating from AWS Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, amazon-kinesis

My team and I have a streaming system based on the Kinesis service from Amazon, that delivers tracking information to other teams using Java standalone consumers and the KCL. We've decided to migrate this system to  Google Cloud Platform.

We understand that the natural replacement of Amazon Kinesis in the Google Platform is the Google Cloud Dataflow service. Is that right?

Other concern is about data partition, because we use the user-id as a partition key in Kinesis. Is it posible to do the same partition on Google Dataflow?

And of course, has anyone done a migration like this o a similar migration from AWS to the Google Platform before? Any advise?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Cloud Dataflow would be the correct alternative, and you probably also want to consider Cloud Pub/Sub as your messaging middleware if you want to use topics and subscriptions.

Partitioning data by keys is totally possible in Dataflow, but you don't need to decide on a single partition key for your entire pipeline. Instead, when you are ready to do aggregation operations, you just define a GroupByKey transform and Dataflow will correctly shard your data into buckets and process them in a distributed fashion over many workers in parallel. Each worker will own a subrange of your keys.

You can have multiple GroupByKeys in a sequence and they can use different keys to do sharding and aggregations.

A recent example of a former AWS user migrating to GCP (specifically, Dataflow) would be Brightcove. Here is a recording of their GCP Next session https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BrcmUqWNm0&feature=youtu.be&t=29m30s